# Trying to read JSON but something is not working

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to read JSON with the below code. The JSON below is just the beginning of the complete string which is the complete JSON string which I actually use.

I am trying to iterate through all symbols where my MessageBox is but the code never reach there.

I wonder what I can be doing wrong. The MessageBoxes shows some info below?

```
        {"tickers":{"ADA/CAD":{"symbol":"ADA/CAD","timestamp":1550084131415,"datetime":"2019-02-13T18:55:31.415Z","high":0.060799,"low":0.05358,"bid":0.053814,"ask":0.054435,
        "vwap":0.054506,"open":0.060799,"close":0.057262,"last":0.057262,"baseVolume":371734.41303949,"quoteVolume":20261.755917130442,
        "info":{"a":["0.054435","1975","1975.000"],"b":["0.053814","12382","12382.000"],"c":["0.057262","399.00000000"],
        "v":["368734.41303949","371734.41303949"],"p":["0.054494","0.054506"],"t":[65,69],"l":["0.053580","0.053580"],"h":["0.060799","0.060799"],"o":"0.060799"}},   
        //I have red all JSON into responseBody string
        String responseBody = ""; 


        JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
        dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
        if (stuff != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This messagebox is shown");

            dynamic tickers = stuff.tickers;
            for (int i = 0; i < tickers.Count; i++)
            {
                dynamic symbol = tickers[i].symbol;
                if (symbol != null)
                {
                    //This messagebox is not shown??
                    MessageBox.Show(symbol.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is nothing to iterate. `tickers` is an JSON Object, not an Array. Please post the full JSON payload and i might be able to figure something out for you.

Comment: I see JSON is not something I usually use but I would be very happy if you can see if you can have any idéa how to do it. I try to add the complete JSON in my question then.

Comment: All JSON doesn't fit in the question. It is to much text. What can I do? I could create a file and upload it to the web but I am not sure if posting links is allowed?

Comment: you could create a `new paste` [here](https://pastebin.com/) save it and comment the link.

Comment: Thanks that worked, the link is: https://pastebin.com/yU7C6Wef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tickers` object consists of KeyValuePairs, so you can deserialize it to a Dictionary.

```
//json is your JSON string
var deserializedTickers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TickersRoot>(json);

foreach(var ticker in deserializedTickers.Tickers)
{
    // ticker.Key is "ADA/CAD" for example 
    // and in ticker.Value is all the data relating to that key
    var symbol = ticker.Value.Symbol;
    if (symbol != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(symbol.ToString());
    }
}
```

I also converted your JSON into a class structure, so you can work more efficiently without having to rely on `dynamic`:

```
public class TickersRoot
{
    public Dictionary<string, Ticker> Tickers { get; set; }
}

public class Ticker
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Bid { get; set; }
    public double Ask { get; set; }
    public double Vwap { get; set; }
    public double Open { get; set; }
    public double Close { get; set; }
    public double Last { get; set; }
    public double BaseVolume { get; set; }
    public double QuoteVolume { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public List<string> a { get; set; }
    public List<string> b { get; set; }
    public List<string> c { get; set; }
    public List<string> v { get; set; }
    public List<string> p { get; set; }
    public List<int> t { get; set; }
    public List<string> l { get; set; }
    public List<string> h { get; set; }
    public string o { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tobias, your solution is excellent. I will use this solution. It was great how you put in classes so it is possible to call the different variables in that way. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Andreas that's great to hear! Make sure you mark it as the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: Yes I just marked it as answer. Yes absolutetly! Working with your code now. It is great ;)

Comment: I am sorry. I really clicked both as answers, the webbrowser must have not reacted the second time. But now I have made it correct.. thank you for telling me :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the *dynamic* for this case because the variable type will be resolved on runtime, leaving you without knowing what the actual type is and how to work with it. Here's a quick solution for your problem so you can get a better idea of how you can iterate over a JObject using LINQ.

```
        JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
        if (parsedJson != null)
        {
            JToken tickers = parsedJson["tickers"];
            List<string> tickerKeys = tickers.Value<JObject>()
                .Properties()
                .Select(p => p.Name)
                .ToList();

            foreach(string key in tickerKeys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tickers[key]["symbol"]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That is great, I made it work with that code. I will check on that approach. Thank you for this solution!

Comment: Feel free to mark my solution as an answer for other people. Glad I could help